# How to get the matching data in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, contains

I am trying to get the matching data in list by passing a key word.Below the code.

```
lst = [{'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Primary-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'},{'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Secondary-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'},{'Name': 'an1-te1-atrmm-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'}]
Key = ['ea']
newlst = []

for i in lst:
    newlst.append(i['Name'])
    #print(i['Name'])     
    for j in newlst:
        if j.__contains__(key):
            print('yes')
```

But Excepting output be like `op = [{'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Primary-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'},{'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Secondary-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'}]`

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a `list comprehension` and the `in` operator:

```
lst = [{
    'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Primary-Asg',
    'Region': 'us-east-2'
}, {
    'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Secondary-Asg',
    'Region': 'us-east-2'
}, {
    'Name': 'an1-te1-atrmm-Asg',
    'Region': 'us-east-2'
}]
key = ['an1-te1-atrmm-Asg']
newlst = []

op = [subDict for subDict in lst if subDict.get('Name') in key]
print(op)
```

Out:

```
[{'Name': 'an1-te1-atrmm-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'}]
```

Comment: if i search with the any key  word .. need to get op like [{'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Primary-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'},{'Name': 'an1-cs-ea-Secondary-Asg', 'Region': 'us-east-2'}]

Comment: @Thentumatcha: What do you mean ?

Comment: @Thentumatcha: You possibly what to invert the condition: `if key in subDict.get('Name')`